# npm tileserver-gl exits when running on Windows Server 2016

Tags: node-js, tile-server, tileserver-gl, windows-server-2016

I am facing an issue with tileserver-gl installed with npm.

I installed node `20.9.0` (the problem also persisted on the `21.6.1`) on Windows Server 2016.

I installed `tileserver-gl` using `npm install -g tileserver-gl`.

I then ran the server using `npx tileserver-gl --verbose --file osm.mbtiles --port 8282`

Soon as I open the http://localhost:8282 the server stops (See attachment).

But if I move the basic-preview styles out of the folder, the server runs but I can only query .pbf and I need to query .png file

The same configuration works on Windows 11 .

[image: server stopping after opening the url]

[image: Style configuration]